# Jekyll Liquid limit contains

Tags: if-statement, jekyll, liquid

I would like to limit how many posts show which contains the layout project but doing this just limits my posts. If I put the limit:4 after the contains, I'm met with;

> Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 50): Expected end_of_string but found pipe in "post.layout contains "project" | limit:1" in /_layouts/home.html
>
> Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 56): Expected end_of_string but found id in "post.layout contains "project" limit:4 offset:1" in /_layouts/home.html

Hoping somebody here will easily see where I am going wrong. An explanation would be lovely also.

```
{% for post in site.posts %} 
  {% if post.layout contains "project" | limit:1 %}
  <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.layout contains "project" limit:4 offset:1 %}
  <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce but `"post.layout contains "project" limit:1"` is the interesting part. Do you have repository url ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Yeah (https://github.com/spskeen/sequel) I just want to show my 'project' post but limit it to 4. If there is a better way of doing this, I'll do that haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `limit` and `offset` in a for loop. 
Here you use it in an `if` statement, that's why you get the warning.

The better approach is to use where_exp filter.

```
  {% assign project-posts = site.posts | where_exp: "post", "post.layout contains 'project'"  %}

  {% for post in project-posts limit: 1 %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for post in project-posts limit:4 offset:1 %}
    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
  {% endfor %}
```